# Quienes sean descendientes, o persona asimilada a "este"

Tags: significado-en-contexto

Quisiera preguntar a qué se refiere "este" en "[quienes sean descendientes, o persona asimilada a este, de la persona asegurada o de su cónyuge, aunque estén separados judicialmente...](https://www.puntoseguro.com/blog/quien-tiene-derecho-la-sanidad-publica-en-espana/#beneficiarios)". Al principio pensaba que se refería a "descendientes", pero "este"es singular y mientras "descendientes" es plural. ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El lenguaje jurídico puede ser confuso;

Tendrán la condición de beneficiarios de un asegurado quienes sean descendientes, o persona asimilada a **este**, *(no vas desencaminado*, es decir, "*o persona similar a un pariente que no sea descendiente*", con "**este**" se refiere a los descendientes en el sentido de que ellos tienen el status de "**pariente**" y pariente se sobrentiende que es forma singular. Así, "**asimiladas**" significa que esta consideración también tiene efectos jurídicos o legales como en los descendientes hacia otras personas, es decir, en este caso pueden ser otros parientes o personas a cargo del asegurado).

> de la persona asegurada o de su cónyuge, aunque estén separados
> judicialmente de su ex cónyuge a cargo o de su pareja de hecho, en
> ambos casos a cargo del asegurado y menor de 26 años o, en caso de ser
> mayor de dicha edad, que tenga una discapacidad reconocida en un grado
> igual o superior al 65 %.

Más abajo te dice quien son las personas asimiladas que le corresponde el beneficio aparte de los descendientes;

> **Además, tendrán la consideración de personas asimiladas a los descendientes las siguientes:**
>
> - **Los menores sujetos a la tutela** o al acogimiento legal de una persona
>   asegurada, **de su cónyuge**, aunque esté separado judicialmente,
>   o de **su pareja de hecho**, así como de **su ex cónyuge a cargo** cuando, en
>   este último caso, la tutela o el acogimiento se hubiesen producido
>   antes del divorcio o de la nulidad matrimonial.
> - **Las hermanas y los hermanos** de la persona asegurada.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por las detalladas explicaciones de Ustedes! Ahora lo entiendo perfectamente ~

Comment: Y, ¡Felices fiestas!

Comment: Gracias a ti por el comentario y desearte igualmente unas Felices Fiestas Navideñas. ¡Cuídate!

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por sus buenos deseos!

Answer (score 1):

En el texto puede observarse que se usaron plurales para todos los ítems:

> - Quienes sean cónyuges de la persona asegurada o convivan con ella en situación de pareja de hecho.
> - Los que sean ex cónyuges o estén separados judicialmente, en ambos casos a cargo de la persona asegurada por tener derecho a percibir una pensión compensatoria por parte de esta.
> - Quienes sean descendientes, o persona asimilada a este, de la persona asegurada o de su cónyuge, aunque estén separados judicialmente, de su ex cónyuge a cargo o de su pareja de hecho, en ambos casos a cargo del asegurado y menor de 26 años o, en caso de ser mayor de dicha edad, que tenga una discapacidad reconocida en un grado igual o superior al 65 %.
>
> Además, tendrán la consideración de personas asimiladas a los descendientes las siguientes:
>
> - Los menores sujetos a la tutela o al acogimiento legal de una persona asegurada, de su cónyuge, aunque esté separado judicialmente, o de su pareja de hecho, así como de su ex cónyuge a cargo cuando, en este último caso, la tutela o el acogimiento se hubiesen producido antes del divorcio o de la nulidad matrimonial.
> - Las hermanas y los hermanos de la persona asegurada.

Además, considerando que la oración entre los puntos habla de "personas asimiladas a los descendientes", puede concluirse que "persona asimilada a este" es un error: debería decir "personas asimiladas a estos".